# Query to set variable depending on query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table TempResults with column Point, Value.

```
Point   Value
ZM1        0
ZM1-2   0,00023587
```

I'm trying to write SQL query: I need when value of any point =0 then set @dev=1, when both values not equal to zero @dev=2. My query set @dev=2 if one of any value not equal to zero.

```
DECLARE @DEV int;
SELECT @DEV = CASE 
WHEN Value=0 THEN 1
ELSE 2
END
FROM TempResults WHERE Point='ZM1' or Point = 'ZM1-2'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select @dev = min(case when value = 0 then 1 else 2 end)
from tempresults
where point in ('ZM1', 'ZM1-2')
```

Basically the `case` expression turns `0` values to `1` and others to `2`; all that is left to do is compute the minimum computed value in the group. If there is any `0`, you get `1`, else `2`.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need !